# Any reference to RESTful api/orOther which shows updated data periodically?

Tags: php, rest

We can see data on some sites which show "hour based or daily based" data.

I googled but could not get helpful reference.

Any idea about php implementation for "how to show records updated by every hour".

My record in the data base keep changing. I want to show three most frequent data on my page and which should be updated every hour/day.

If any other such API exist that is also fine.

Comment: There are multiple approaches to do this. The easiest is Long Polling. Another approach is socket-based approach. When ever a change occurs at server end, that change is propagated to all clients.

Comment: @timus2001: I thought only restful api can do it

Comment: You can do it with REST API too, but don't even think that using REST API, you will get notifications automatically. You will still have to implement your notification system using one of the methods I mentioned above.

Comment: REST API is only a way you are using to access your data or other resources. So maybe there is a DAL layer underneath your API that interacts with your database.